# Compute the complex Fourier series from $f(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

I'm stuck on this task.

> Compute the complex Fourier series on the $2\pi$-periodic function: $$f(x)=\sin(2x) + 6\cos(3x)$$

I know that $a_n = 6$ when $n=3$, and $b_n=1$ when $n=2$. But, how do I now compute the complex Fourier series?

Comment: I just fixed your grammar typos and formatting, but you should add more context to your question so that everyone can understand yours.

Comment: What's wrong with integrating against $e^{inx}$? If you can do this for integrating against $\sin,\cos$, you can surely do it for integrating against $e^{inx}$